# nodejs helloworld test app not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

I am new to learning node.js and I downloaded all the components on ubuntu. I have written a test, helloworld app, but it does not work for some reason. Here's my file layout.

When I execute which nodejs, the terminal returns /usr/bin/nodejs

When I execute which npm, the terminal returns /usr/bin/npm

My app.js test file is located in /home/tarang/node/helloWorld

Here's the source for the app.js

```
//creating http server
var http = require('require');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Context-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('helloWorld');
}).listen(8000);

console.log('server running');
```

**UPDATE**

When i execute nodejs app.js, i obtain the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'require'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tarang/node/helloWorld/app.js:4:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Please do explain since I am new to ubuntu and nodejs.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Do i need to update to the lastest verions of express, node and npm?

Comment: Just updated it. Please have a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to import the `http` module, not `require`, so

```
//creating http server
var http = require('http');
```

Comment: Also, why do some websites say I need to use node app.js to execute it, while I have to use nodejs app.js to execute it? Is this a version issues?

Comment: The Ubuntu node package is non-standard, and changes the executable name to `nodejs`. It *should* be `node` but you'll have to take that up with package maintainers.

Comment: So I guess, if it works, it works? I don't need to be worried about it, right?

Comment: Yah, especially if you're just getting started. Later you can check out [using a ppa](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os). It's usually a little more up to date.

Comment: But it does say that I have the lastest version of nodejs. nodejs --version returns v0.10.25

Comment: The latest is `0.10.29`

Answer (score 1):

Issue is likely because you haven't installed the require module prior to running. You need to run `npm install require` on the command line before running the server, otherwise it won't be able to find the module.

Comment: I just did that, and it returned the same error. I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: You can also install it globally: npm install -g require

Comment: confirm that you now have a `node_modules` directory in the same directory as your app.js?

Comment: How do i do that? I'm really confused. I assume the error is because node cannot find some of the necessary files

Comment: `ls -ltr` on the ubuntu command line ...that being the case, i'm not entirely sure why you're using require in the first place?  If you're just trying to replicate the Node basic tutorial, you should use the http module, not the require module.

Comment: I don't seem to have the node_modules directory. I was just following a youtube video and it worked for him

Comment: OK well that's your issue.  In order for any module to be used by node, you need to run the appropriate install command for the module (such as `npm install require`) on the linux command line, and then '''restart''' the server.  If you are doing this and it still isn't showing up, then you need to post the output of the npm install command

Comment: Well, apparently I was confused and used require('require') instead of require('http') it works now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

the `require` module is missing according to the error message.

cd to the app root directory, run this:

`npm install --save`

**Edit:**

Hey wait, why are you `require('require')`?

I beleieve it should be `require('http')` instead

Comment: So cd to the location where node was installed i.e. usr/bin/nodejs ?

Comment: nope, the root direectory of your app, which should be `/home/tarang/node/helloWorld` I believe.

Comment: the terminal returns "could not read dependencies". Why is this so complicateD?

Comment: so i beleieve you dont have a package.json yet. see my answer after a few mins while i am editing :D

Comment: I don't think I have a package.json yet. I am following this tutorial. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socketio-and-expressjs--net-31708